# Elixir Absinthe app with Task timeout that I can't find

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, absinthe

I've got a big phoenix project using absinthe and on the graphql call, I get the error if the request takes longer than 5s

```
#PID<0.8144.0> running RLWeb.Endpoint (connection #PID<0.8143.0>, stream id 1) terminated
Server: app.com:80 (http)
Request: POST /v1/graphql
** (exit) exited in: Task.await(%Task{mfa: {:erlang, :apply, 2}, owner: #PID<0.8144.0>, pid: #PID<0.8200.0>, ref: #Reference<0.4122125287.2851143681.49992>}, 5000)
```

I've looked for every use of `Task` and can't find anywhere I'm using it with the default 5000 timeout. I have no idea how to debug this. Do you know know where I can start to figure out where this is happening?

Comment: it's probably not a `Task` that you're using directly, it's probably something that is getting called indirectly.  If you're using GraphQL, verify whether this issue happens on every query or if it's something that happens only with a specific query or resolver.  Unfortunately, the error is too vague to offer specific suggestions.